# How to use accepts_nested_attributes_for with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read these documents:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for
- http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

My source:

## Model

app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_items, foreign_key: :product_id, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_items
end
```

app/models/product_item.rb

```
class ProductItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

## Controller

app/controllers/products_controller.rb

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, product_items_attributes: [ :description ])
  end
end
```

## View

app/views/products/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(product, url: path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :product_items do |item_form| %>
    <%= item_form.label :description %>
    <%= item_form.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

I can save the product data to the database, but it can't save product_items.

---

## Edit

Add my post data after submit my form:

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:c5sdmoyLoN01Fxa55q6ahTQripx0GZvWU/d27C]asfdawofX9gw==
product[name]:apple
product[product_items][description]:good
commit:Submit
```

---

## Edit 2

Add rails log:

```
Started POST "/products" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-09-15 13:00:57 +0900
Processing by ProductController#create as HTML
I, [2015-09-15T13:00:58.039924 #28053]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bilBzgOLc2/ZRUFhJORn+CJvCHkVJSsHQTg1V/roifoHxi9IRA==", "product"=>{"name"=>"apple", "product_items"=>{"description"=>"good"}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: you should be building your product_items by @product.build_product_items. It should work

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff It should be `@product.product_items.build` as it is a `has_many` association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `new` method should like below in order to save `product_items`

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.product_items.build
end
```

You should also change your `product_params` like below for the ***update*** to work correctly in *future*.

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, product_items_attributes: [ :id, :description ])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller action `product_params`

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, product_items_attributes: [:id, :description, :_destroy ])
end
```

Either you can use `nested_form` gem which provide you complete demo and function control. Here is link https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your method, but the result was the same. Even I saw `nested_form`, it seems old and only works for Rails 3. Now I am using Rails 4.

Comment: can you post your request params here which you are getting while submitting request

Comment: Can you post the same thing from rails console log. Actually I want to see what are structure of params hash in rails console and log of controller action.Thanks

Comment: I have posted the rails log information. They are the same except format.